# Como obtener dos ids de dos etiquetas mediante click

Tags: jquery

estoy intentando de hacer un sitema de **votaciones** simple y se me da la nececidad de obtener dos **ids** de dos etiquetas mediante un `click` para asi obtener el id del **post** y cual voto pulso el usuario como obtenerlo?

lo intente de la siguiente manera pero no lo consigo...

```
   <ul class="vote-container">
    <li id="vote-up"><span id="<?php echo$id;?>"><i class="fas fa-angle-up"></i></span></li>

    <li id="vote-down"><span id="<?php echo$id;?>"><i class="fas fa-angle-down"></i></span></li>
 </ul>
```

$(function(){

```
$(".vote-container li").click(function(){


      var vote=$(this).attr("id");//id de la etiqueta li
      var id_vote=$(this).next("span").attr("id");//intento recojer el id de la etiqueta span


         console.log(vote+" "+id_vote);
```

esto me devuelve como resultado

> vote-up undefined

alguien me puede dar una idea de como hacer lo que nececito gracias!

Comment: Tu etiqueta span no tiene id, por lo que es normal que te de undefined.

Answer (score 1):

Para que funcione tu código cambia `$(this).next(...)` a `$(this).find(...)`

```js
$(function() {

  $(".vote-container li").click( function() {

      var vote = $(this).attr("id");
      var id_vote = $(this).find("span").attr("id");
      console.log(vote+" "+id_vote);         
  });
});
```

```html
<ul class="vote-container">
  <li id="vote-up"><span id="123"><i class="fas fa-angle-up"></i></span>click me 123</li>
  <li id="vote-down"><span id="456"><i class="fas fa-angle-down"></i></span>click me 456</li>
</ul>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```